# Detect movement up, down, left, right on mapView in Titanium

Tags: javascript, google-maps, titanium, appcelerator

I need to detect when te user moves the map that is showing on the mapView. For example when I move the map right I need to detect that movement but I don't now wish event I need to use. I have tried all this event but non has worked.

```
mapView.addEventListener('center_changed', function(e){
console.log("Teste");
});

mapView.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
console.log("Teste");
});

mapView.addEventListener('dragend', function(e){
console.log("Teste");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can just start and guess what the event will be, but you can also look at the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.View-event-regionchanged). It clearly specifies 10 events including `regionchanged`.

If you create a map using alloy, you can also bind the event in the xml with `onRegionchanged="myRegionchangeFunction"`